# Pandas - take() does not accept boolean indexers

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I need to create the new Dataframe from old df, that contains defined columns.

```
model_columns = ['dist', 'date_day', 'is_holiday', 'date_dayofweek', 'date_month',
                'tech', 'cap', 'HEIGHT', 'AZIMUTH', 'x', 'y'] // and other columns


X_train = df_train[model_columns]


<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 720384 entries, 0 to 285510
Data columns (total 18 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------          --------------   -----         
 0   ID              720384 non-null  int64         
 1   date_           720384 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 2   spd             720384 non-null  float64       
 3   subs            720384 non-null  float64       
 4   trf             720384 non-null  float64       
 5   y               720384 non-null  int64         
 6   x               720384 non-null  int64         
 7   tech            720384 non-null  int64         
 8   cap             720384 non-null  float64       
 9   HEIGHT          720384 non-null  float64       
 10  AZIMUTH         720384 non-null  int64         
 11  date_m          720384 non-null  period[M]     
 12  date_month      720384 non-null  int64         
 13  day_dayofweek   720384 non-null  int64         
 14  is_holiday      720384 non-null  bool          
 15  date_dayofweek  720384 non-null  int64         
 16  date_day        720384 non-null  int64         
 17  dist            720384 non-null  float64       
dtypes: bool(1), datetime64[ns](1), float64(6), int64(9), period[M](1)
```

But I get error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-4fc28e7d3d66> in <module>
----> 1 X_train = df_train[model_columns] # # take() does not accept boolean indexers
```

and

```
KeyError: "['y_100', 'y_30', 'y_200', 'x_100', 'xy_100', 'xy', 'y_500', 'xy_50', 'xy_200', 'x_30', 'x_200', 'xy_30', 'x_500'] not in index"
```

What I should do there? Probably there df has wrond index?

Comment: They key error is showing other variables than the original ```model_columns ```, how is that?

Comment: yeah, there was variables not contained in df_train. Just my mistake, but pandas errors often are strange and hard to understand.